# How to import Typescript definition of Dropbox API types?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, dropbox-api

I'm making a browser app in VS Code in Typescript that uses the Dropbox SDK.

This import works:

```js
import { Dropbox, DropboxAuth, DropboxResponse, DropboxResponseError } from 'dropbox';
```

This upload code works too:

```js
const uploadResult = await dropbox.filesUpload(
   {path: constants.dropboxFilename, contents: journalString});
```

But when I write this, to allow overwriting in uploads and prevent 409 error:

```js
const uploadResult = await dropbox.filesUpload(
   {path: constants.dropboxFilename, contents: journalString, mode: WriteModeOverwrite});
```

I can't get access to the definition of `WriteModeOverwrite` because it's in `node_modules/dropbox/types/dropbox_types.d.ts`

How do I add this definitions file to my project, so both VS Code and TSC see it?

My project seems to see only `node_modules/dropbox/types/index.d.ts` automatically. Thanks.

---

More info:

I tried adding `import * as dropboxTypes from 'dropbox/types/dropbox_types';` too, but `dropboxTypes.` anything is empty and autocomplete doesn't find any filemodes.

The `mode` property has hint: `files.CommitInfo.mode?: files.WriteMode | undefined` but if I try setting it to `files.WriteMode` or `WriteModeOverwrite` or `files.WriteModeOverwrite` it's a type error. VS Code can't autocomplete anything on `files`.

If I set the property to `'overwrite'` the code doesn't compile without error, but runs and uploads perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I empathize with you as this is (understandably) an unclear type. It appears that the types for this library are generated and the publishers haven't thoroughly considered the ergonomics of usage.

From [dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js#207 (comment)](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/issues/207#issuecomment-400070287):

> `WriteMode` is a union, not a string, so you'll need to specify it like this:
>
> ```
> this.dropbox.filesUpload({contents: fileContent, path: fileName, mode:{".tag": "overwrite"}})
> ```

Dropbox really should provide an exported enum for you to use here.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76051401/438273) has explained how you can import the `files` namespace and find the needed type — that's great!

But what if you didn't have access to that type (or the name of the type changes in the future, etc.)?

You can use TypeScript to infer the needed type using a few [utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html). Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#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)

```ts
import type { Dropbox } from "dropbox";

// This is the type that represents the first parameter for the `filesUpload` method:
type UploadArg = Parameters<Dropbox["filesUpload"]>[0];
   //^? type UploadArg = files.UploadArg

// This type represents the `mode` property of the type above:
type WriteMode = UploadArg["mode"];
   //^? type WriteMode = files.WriteMode | undefined

// However, it's still not obvious what `files.WriteMode` means...
// Utility types can be used to determine that:

type WriteModeKey = keyof NonNullable<WriteMode>;
   //^? type WriteModeKey = ".tag"

type WriteModeTagValue = NonNullable<WriteMode>[".tag"];
   //^? type WriteModeTagValue = "overwrite" | "add" | "update"

// Bingo! We need a type like this:
type WriteModeOverwrite = Extract<WriteMode, { ".tag": "overwrite" }>;
   //^? type WriteModeOverwrite = files.WriteModeOverwrite

// It can be used to annotate your `mode` value like this:
const mode: WriteModeOverwrite = { ".tag": "overwrite" };

declare const dropbox: Dropbox;
declare const otherProps: Pick<UploadArg, "path" | "contents">;

dropbox.filesUpload({
  ...otherProps,
  mode,
}); // Ok
```

Comment: Thank you, `mode:{".tag": "overwrite"}`  both compiles, and is accepted by Dropbox when I upload. The other other answer compiles but doesn't run correctly. I will have to read your answer thoroughly to understand it and unfortunately I probably won't have Internet till next week.

Answer (score 1):

According to what I see, you shouldn't need to do anything to get this to work. [types/index.d.ts](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/main/types/index.d.ts) does `export * from './dropbox_types';`, and `WriteModeOverwrite` is exported from types/dropbox_types.d.ts within the `files` namespace. I think you just need to add `files` to your list of imports (in `import {...} from 'dropbox'`) and then use `files.WriteModeOverwrite`. Ex.

```ts
import { type files } from "dropbox"
let foo: files.WriteModeOverwrite;
```

`let foo` is just an example of using the type in a type context ("foo" is a pretty standard example-variable name). You can use `files.WriteModeOverwrite` in whatever type context you want. The fact that you can't use it where you want to use it is because you're **not supposed to use it like that**- that's not a type context. That's a value context (the value part of an object's key-value entry)... what are you even trying to do? You need to put a *value there* and then type-annotate it / type-assert it. Ex.

Unfortunately, I don't actually know what you're supposed to use there. It's either `"overwrite"`, or `{".tag": "overwrite"}`. [Searching public GitHub repos, I see both in usage](https://github.com/search?q=dropbox+filesUpload+mode&type=Code). It doesn't help that [the official upload example](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js/blob/main/examples/typescript/upload/upload.ts) doesn't show usage of that argument (at the time of this writing). Try both and see which actually does what you expect.

Comment: I get "error TS2305: Module '"dropbox"' has no exported member 'WriteModeOverwrite'.". It sees the other parts of Dropbox, just not that. I have dropbox in my tsconfig.json too. TSC still can't see the WriteMode

Comment: @user Good research!

Comment: Ok, this works, thanks, but I  have questions. 1) Why can't I use `mode: files.WriteModeOverwrite`, why does it need to go into `foo` first? 2) Why does `let foo...` need to be at the top of the file? If I put it just above my call to dropbox I get the `variable assigned before used` error, which is not true I don't think

Comment: Ah, no, actually your code compiles, but it doesn't actually work. Dropbox rejects the file unless I change it to `mode: 'overwrite'`